# How to store variable and select where in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#

I have this set of code which will return the sum of `SelisihLoadSchAct` column where column `SchLoadSubVessel` equal to variable `SubVesselName` and `SchLoadVessel` equal to SubVoyageNo to variable with data type of double called `SisaSelisihSchLoad`

```
double SisaSelisihSchLoad = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
.Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value));
```

and now the problem is, how do i just select? not sum? i tried changing sum to select but it return error instead or am i doing something wrong with the select statement?

edit: updated problem

how do i use `%` just like in query? as example `SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Column1 LIKE 'SubVesselName%'`

Comment: What do you mean by you want to select it? Do you want the rows (`DataGridViewRow`)? Or all of the individual values (`decimal`)?

Comment: i just want the single individual values, just like how you get a single value from many rows and column by using `select column from table where column1=a and column2=b`

Comment: updated how do i use the `%` just like in query? as example `SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Column1 LIKE 'SubVesselName%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is strongly typed, so if you just change from `Sum` to `Select` you get wrong types, as you try to assign collection to `double`.

You can just change `Sum` to `Select`, but you also ned to change the type of `SisaSelisihSchLoad`. You can use `var` and let Visual figure it out on its own,
or you could declare something like `double[]` (or `List<double>`) and after `Select` call additional method `ToArray` (or `ToList`).

```
var SisaSelisihSchLoad = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value));

double[] SisaSelisihSchLoad = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value)).ToArray();

Lisst<double> SisaSelisihSchLoad = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: This indeed answer my question but it turn out i need to use `%` in the variable, as example in `SubVesselName`, how do i make it like query `select column from table where column1= 'SubVesselName%' ` ?

Comment: @radren Unfortunately it's not possible the ay you want it.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn What about `string.StartsWith()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like all of the individual values, you need to call `Select()` on the value you want to get out and then put them into an `IEnumerable<T>`.

I am using `var` below to let the compiler choose the type for me so I don't have to update it if the type changes. if you want to specify it it can be anything derived from `IEnumerable<T>` (e.g. `List<T>`, `decimal[]`, etc.)

```
var SisaSelisihSchLoads = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName 
             && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
    .Select(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value));
```

EDIT:

As per your edited question, you can change the `Where()` to be similar to the `SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COLUMN] like 'value%'` by using the string method `.StartsWith()` like so:

```
var SisaSelisihSchLoads = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value).StartsWith(SubVesselName) 
             && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
    .Select(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

On your case

```cs
Sum() => return double
Select() => return IEnumerable<double>
```

Example

```cs
// Store sum of SelisihLoadSchAct
double SisaSelisihSchLoad = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
.Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value));

// Store list of SelisihLoadSchAct
IEnumerable<int> SisaSelisihSchLoad = dgv_bulkclink.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadSubVessel"].Value) == SubVesselName && Convert.ToString(r.Cells["SchLoadVessel"].Value) == SubVoyageNo)
.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["SelisihLoadSchAct"].Value));
```